# XNA Windows Phone Touch Gestures

Tags: c#, xna

I am making a game and I need the user to be able to drag the bomb sprite around the screen. When I run my code I'm only able to move my sprite to the RIGHT. Heres my code:

```
 public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        TouchPanel.EnabledGestures =
            GestureType.FreeDrag;

        while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
        {
            GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();

            foreach (Bomb instance in bombs)
            {
                if (gesture.Position.X > instance.position.X && gesture.Position.Y < instance.position.X + texture.Width && gesture.Position.Y > instance.position.Y && gesture.Position.Y < instance.position.Y + texture.Height)
                {
                    instance.moving = false;

                    instance.position = new Vector2(gesture.Position.X, gesture.Position.Y);
                }
            }
        }
```

The code works if I take out the if statement, but I really cant do this because I am going to have more than one instance of the bomb on the screen. By saying the code works, I mean that I am able to freely move around the sprite all over the screen as I wish. This is what I would like to accomplish. What do you all suggest is going on?